# Getting SharePoint file Permissions using Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Graph explorer allows me to get a file's permissions like so

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{Site-ID}/Lists/{Library name}/items/1191/DriveItem/Permissions
```

Gives all the  I need
But Snippet not available!

Looking in the documentation it shows:

```
var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].Permissions.GetAsync();
```

But for this I need 3 calls:

1. get the {drive-id} from the list
2. get the {driveItem-id} from the item (I have the ID)
3. Get the Permissions

Anyone knows a better way or how to do it in one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least two calls. First call to get `driveItem`

```
var driveItem = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"]
                   .Lists["{list-id}"]
                   .Items["{listItem-id}"]
                   .DriveItem.GetAsync();
```

Use [parentReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itemreference?view=graph-rest-1.0) and its property `driveId` in the second call

```
var permissions = await graphClient.Drives[driveItem.ParentReference.DriveId]
                     .Items[driveItem.Id]
                     .Permissions.GetAsync();
```